# How to make this pattern to be background image?

Tags: css

I have this kind of pattern

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT6WL.png

in big part of PSD, and how would you set this kind of pattern to be background on HTML page. I shouldn't take bit picture right?
Also I tried to cut a peace and repeat it, but it doesn't match, it looks bad and it's distorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

[image: background]

I've just cut a square out of the image you sent and it looks ok IMO.

Comment: yeah this matches great, If you cut it from this picture, I must be able to cut it from PSD than, just need to be more precise

Answer (score 1):

Since we are not aware of the kind of pattern you have, here are some suggestions.

You can use CSS3 patterns if site supports only modern browsers.
If its a pattern sure you can cut a small piece from it & can repeat.

**Some links may help**
http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/
http://www.patternify.com/
http://subtlepatterns.com/
http://24ways.org/2011/css3-patterns-explained
http://bgpatterns.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link http://lea.verou.me/2010/12/checkered-stripes-other-background-patterns-with-css3-gradients/ if you are allowed to use CSS3. This will get you the desired effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.stripegenerator.com/

Answer (score 0):

CHECK this:: [patternify.com](http://www.patternify.com)

i make a bg image similar to yours with this tool, in fact is so easy n__n