# crop image for css background pattern

Tags: css, photoshop

Could anyone help me to crop this dragon scale for css background pattern? I have tried to crop this by myself but still it was not precise. Thank you in advance!

Dragon scale pattern : 
http://cl.ly/image/471U3s3T1V2e

Comment: Not what StackOverflow is for

Comment: There's a question related that has been asked in here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278373/how-to-make-this-pattern-to-be-background-image

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for image manipulation services.

Comment: This question appears off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: perhaps some suggestions where I can post this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background images need to be able to tile (or fit the background without tiling).  The image you link to does not have any actual repetition in it, so it would not actually be possible to make it tile by cropping alone.  It would also require quite a bit of re-drawing work.

So, if your question was "how do I", rather than "will you?" - the answer is that you cannot.